# Install react-scripts without postcss

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postcss

I'm trying to upload my code onto a server but it won't allow me because of moderate vulnerabilities. I've narrowed down my issue to an old version postcss downloaded from installing react app, specifically react-scripts. I've tried uninstalling postcss and `react-scripts` then installing `postcss` first, but whenever I do the installation it installs a bad version in its dependencies on `node-modules` folder.

Log of some of the errors in case my issues without `postcss`

```
 Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service                          
  Package         postcss                                                       
  Patched in      >=8.2.10                                                      
  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 
  Path            react-scripts > postcss-preset-env > postcss-place > postcss  
  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693                             

  Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service                          
  Package         postcss                                                       
  Patched in      >=8.2.10                                                      
  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 
  Path            react-scripts > postcss-preset-env >                          
                  postcss-pseudo-class-any-link > postcss                       
  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693                             

  Moderate        Regular Expression Denial of Service                          
  Package         postcss                                                       
  Patched in      >=8.2.10                                                      
  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 
  Path            react-scripts > postcss-preset-env >                          
                  postcss-replace-overflow-wrap > postcss                       
  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693
```

Log of my uninstall/reinstall to show its the react-scripts

```
found 79 moderate severity vulnerabilities in 1994 scanned packages
  79 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
PS C:\Users\pet22\JavaScriptProjects\skp-forum\front> npm uninstall react-scripts
removed 1839 packages and audited 152 packages in 17.069s

10 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

PS C:\Users\pet22\JavaScriptProjects\skp-forum\front> npm i react-scripts        
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\Users\pet22\JavaScriptProjects\skp-forum\front\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js@3.12.1 postinstall C:\Users\pet22\JavaScriptProjects\skp-forum\front\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall C:\Users\pet22\JavaScriptProjects\skp-forum\front\node_modules\ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

Thank you for installing EJS: built with the Jake JavaScript build tool (https://jakejs.com/)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^2.1.3 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.13.12 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.

+ react-scripts@4.0.3
added 1839 packages from 659 contributors and audited 1994 packages in 57.301s

139 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 79 moderate severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

`npm audit` fix does nothing for me.

Question: How do I install react-scripts without installing postcss lower than 8.2.10?

Comment: Some extra info : issue has been created for the same in create-react-app github: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10945

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem for myself temporarily with better npm audit.  [better npm audit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-npm-audit)

You have to create some .nsprc file on top level and add the exception according the example (number 1693). Put the audit command into the package.json and maybe change the build script (instead of "npm audit" you should use "npm run audit").

This is not fixing the original issue, but at least builds are not failing anymore.